# Permission errors when deploying NextJs and with SST to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy an SST (https://sst.dev/) app with NextJs to AWS, but I am getting some errors. I was having issues with IAM permissions, so was playing around in the AWS console - the original errors seem to have resolved, but I think I deleted something I shouldn't have from the CloudFormation console, so now I cannot delete the SSTBootstrap stack, as its status is DELETION_FAILED. I have read a lot of the documentation on fixing this but nothing seems to work for me (e.g. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-delete-failed, https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-lambda-resource-delete etc).

In my terminal I get the following logs/errors:

```
⠏ Deploying bootstrap stack, this only needs to happen once!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!                                                                            !!
!!  Node 16 has reached end-of-life on 2023-09-11 and is not supported.       !!
!!  Please upgrade to a supported node version as soon as possible.           !!
!!                                                                            !!
!!  This software is currently running on node v16.20.2.                      !!
!!  As of the current release of this software, supported node releases are:  !!
!!  - ^20.0.0 (Planned end-of-life: 2026-04-30)                               !!
!!  - ^18.0.0 (Planned end-of-life: 2025-04-30)                               !!
!!                                                                            !!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://557419670811/us-east-1...
Using default execution policy of 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'. Pass '--cloudformation-execution-policies' to customize.
CDKToolkit: creating CloudFormation changeset...
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:41 | REVIEW_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CDKToolkit User Initiated
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:49 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CDKToolkit User Initiated
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::ECR::Repository    | ContainerAssetsRepository
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role          | LookupRole
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::S3::Bucket         | StagingBucket
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role          | ImagePublishingRole
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role          | FilePublishingRole
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::SSM::Parameter     | CdkBootstrapVersion
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::IAM::Role          | CloudFormationExecutionRole
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | LookupRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | ImagePublishingRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | FilePublishingRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | CloudFormationExecutionRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:54 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::S3::Bucket         | StagingBucket cdk-hnb659fds-assets-557419670811-us-east-1 already exists
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:54 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::SSM::Parameter     | CdkBootstrapVersion Resource creation cancelled
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:54 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::ECR::Repository    | ContainerAssetsRepository Resource creation cancelled
CDKToolkit |  0/12 | 10:23:54 | ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CDKToolkit The following resource(s) failed to create: [ImagePublishingRole, FilePublishingRole, CdkBootstrapVersion, LookupRole, StagingBucket, CloudFormationExecutionRole, ContainerAssetsRepository]. Rollback requested by user.
CDKToolkit |  1/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | ImagePublishingRole
CDKToolkit |  2/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | LookupRole
CDKToolkit |  3/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | FilePublishingRole
CDKToolkit |  4/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::IAM::Role          | CloudFormationExecutionRole
CDKToolkit |  4/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_SKIPPED       | AWS::S3::Bucket         | StagingBucket
CDKToolkit |  5/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::ECR::Repository    | ContainerAssetsRepository
CDKToolkit |  6/12 | 10:23:57 | DELETE_COMPLETE      | AWS::SSM::Parameter     | CdkBootstrapVersion
CDKToolkit |  7/12 | 10:23:57 | ROLLBACK_COMPLETE    | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack | CDKToolkit

Failed resources:
CDKToolkit | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | LookupRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | ImagePublishingRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | FilePublishingRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit | 10:23:53 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::IAM::Role          | CloudFormationExecutionRole API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action
CDKToolkit | 10:23:54 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::S3::Bucket         | StagingBucket cdk-hnb659fds-assets-557419670811-us-east-1 already exists
 ❌  Environment aws://557419670811/us-east-1 failed bootstrapping: Error: The stack named CDKToolkit failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, cdk-hnb659fds-assets-557419670811-us-east-1 already exists
    at FullCloudFormationDeployment.monitorDeployment (/Users/jacobwhitehead/repos/book-maker/node_modules/sst-aws-cdk/lib/index.js:426:10236)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async /Users/jacobwhitehead/repos/book-maker/node_modules/sst-aws-cdk/lib/index.js:431:2104
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async CdkToolkit.bootstrap (/Users/jacobwhitehead/repos/book-maker/node_modules/sst-aws-cdk/lib/index.js:431:1949)
    at async exec4 (/Users/jacobwhitehead/repos/book-maker/node_modules/sst-aws-cdk/lib/index.js:504:52797)

The stack named CDKToolkit failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, API: iam:GetRole User: arn:aws:iam::557419670811:user/book-maker-user is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-557419670811-us-east-1 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:GetRole action, cdk-hnb659fds-assets-557419670811-us-east-1 already exists

✖ Deploying bootstrap stack, this only needs to happen once

Error: Failed to bootstrap
```

Here is the IAM policy for the account trying to deploy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCDKManageToolkitStack",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:112233445566:stack/CDKToolkit/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCDKManageToolkitRoles",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:TagRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCDKManageToolkitBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
                "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cdk-hnb659fds-assets-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCDKManageToolkitRepository",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:112233445566:repository/cdk-hnb659fds-container-assets-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCDKManageToolkitVersionParameter",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:PutParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:112233445566:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTManageBootstrapStack",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:112233445566:stack/SSTBootstrap/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTAssumeCDKToolkitRoles",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-cfn-exec-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-file-publishing-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-image-publishing-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-lookup-role-*",
                "arn:aws:iam::112233445566:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTMonitorStackDeployment",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackEvents",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStackResources",
                "cloudformation:GetTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:112233445566:stack/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTManageBootstrapBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sstbootstrap-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTCLIManageAppSecrets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DeleteParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                "ssm:PutParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:112233445566:parameter/sst/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTCLIRestartAppFunction",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:112233445566:function:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/sst:app": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTLiveLambdaSocketConnection",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:DescribeEndpoint",
                "iot:Connect",
                "iot:Subscribe",
                "iot:Publish",
                "iot:Receive"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTCLIManageRDSMigrations",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-data:ExecuteStatement"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:112233445566:cluster:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/sst:app": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSTConsoleInvokeLambda",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:112233445566:function:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/sst:app": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated. I have attempted to manually delete the SSTBootstrap stack, but it fails every time (both in the CLI and web console); I have even tried to make it ignore the resources in owns, but that didn't work either. Not sure if my IAM permissions are fully correct.